# Encountering "RuntimeError: Legacy model format is not supported on mobile." in Pytorch despite running on desktop

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm attempting to load in serialised PyTorch models in the format sad_player2_model.pth in PyTorch where `torch==1.13.0`. However, I keep running into this error:

```
RuntimeError: Legacy model format is not supported on mobile.
python: /usr/include/boost/fiber/condition_variable.hpp:56: boost::fibers::condition_variable_any::~condition_variable_any(): Assertion `wait_queue_.empty()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As far as I'm aware the models weren't trained on the mobile version of PyTorch and renaming the files to .pt didn't work either. Extracting the archive shows that the model contains the following:

[image: extracted .pth contents]

Comment: Can you please post the code you used to load it?

Comment: I'm attempting to run the model provided [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Hanabi_SPARTA).

More specifically, I downloaded the models by running `download_models.sh`. I then installed the C++ module via `setup.py`.

Next, I ran the command in terminal:

`GREEDY_ACTION=1 TORCHBOT_MODEL=models/sad_player2.pth python eval_bot.py TorchBot --games 1000`

and it encounters the error on line 34 in `eval_bot.py`: 
`hanabi_lib.eval_bot(opt.botname, players=opt.players, games=opt.games, log_every=opt.log_every, seed=opt.seed)`